# how to test the amount of classifier confusion within versus between overarching classes

Tags: hypothesis-testing, classification, pattern-recognition, model-evaluation, confusion-matrix

I am planning a neuroimaging experiment. We present our subjects with 15 items, 5 each in three categories (let's say fruit, animals and people). Each item is presented on 15 instances, for a total of 225 instances (75 per category). We collect multivariate neuroimaging data while subjects view the items.

I plan to train a classifier on each individual's neural data separately to tell apart object identity, using a 1/3 hold-out sample as the test set. The research question is whether the classifier is more likely to confuse two items of the same category (e.g. apples and oranges) than two items of differing categories (e.g. Donald Trump and oranges).

The test should incorporate the data from multiple subjects.

Which test would be appropriate?

Comment: The best I could come up with: 1) make the confusion matrix for every subject 2) count the number of within-category false alarms and the number of between-category false alarms, divide the latter by two (2 times as many items the classifier could confuse the target with), 3) run a paired t-test on these two numbers per person. - This seems crude to me, and I might be overlooking some important bias or so. Any help is appreciated.